# Windows Phone 8.1 Add service reference

Tags: web-services, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, emulation

My problem adding a new service Windows Phone 8.1 but I can't see to tab, 8.1 doesn't add the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with Windows Phone 8.1 Store apps. See the sticky post on the official Developing for Windows Phone forum on MSDN: [WCF Add Service Reference Not Supported for Windows Phone 8.1 XAML Applications](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9ab43a4c-499a-4f2e-81e5-c1ab5acbe9bf/wcf-add-service-reference-not-supported-for-windows-phone-81-xaml-applications?forum=wpdevelop)

Windows Phone Store apps in Windows Phone 8.1 do not support the System.ServiceModel namespace generated by the Add Service Reference menu.

The general recommendation is to expose a REST endpoint from the service rather than a WCF service.

If you cannot add a REST endpoint and must use WCF then either write a Silverlight app instead of a Windows Runtime app or you'll need to write your own code to wrap the WCF conversation.

Comment: you'll need to write your own code to wrap the WCF conversation.
Can you provide any tutorial about this

Comment: I'm not aware of any tutorials. This is probably on the "if you have to ask, it's beyond you" scale: it's possible, but you really need to know what you're doing. The general recommendation is to expose a REST endpoint which is significantly easier to connect to.

Comment: Well I got something very helpful, giving link for everyone else coming here.

https://quirkd.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/shorts-consuming-a-wcf-asmx-web-service-in-winrt/